# Is the difference of these two real-rooted functions real-rooted?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

During our on-going search of approximations to the Riemann $\Xi(z)$ function, we discovered a family of functions $W_n(z)$ as shown in (1).

Our final goal is to prove that:

***Proposition 1:*** $W_{n}(z)$ is real-rooted.

So far we have only been able to prove:

***Theorem 2***
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geqslant 2$, $a_j=\pi^j\frac{2j+1}{(j-1)!}$, $H_{n,-2j}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^{2j}$, $c_{n,j}=a_j H_{n,-2j}$, $q_n=1+9(n+1)^4$. Let
$$W_{n}(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{2q_n} (-1)^{j}c_{n,j}
\left(\mathrm{sinc}(z-i(j+1/4)\ln n)+\mathrm{sinc}(z+i(j+1/4)\ln n)\right)\tag{1}$$

then
(A)
$$W_{n}(z)=\int_{0}^{1}(f_{n,0}(t)-f_{n,1}(t))\cos(zt)\mathrm{d}t=U_{n,0}(z)-U_{n,1}(z)\tag{2}$$
where
$$U_{n,p}(z)=\int_{0}^{1}f_{n,p}(t)\cos(zt)\mathrm{d}t,\quad p=0,1\tag{3}$$
$$f_{n,p}(t)=2\sum_{j=1}^{q_n} c_{n,2j-p}\cosh(t(2j-p+1/4)\ln n)\tag{4}$$
(B) $U_{n,p}(z),p=0,1$ are real-rooted.

(C) Each interval $((2k-1)\pi/2, (2k+1)\pi/2), k \in\mathbb{N}$ contains exactly one zero for $U_{n,p}(z)$.

The proof needs a weaker version of a theorem by Polya (1918)
Uber die Nullstellen gewisser ganzer Funktionen, Math. Z. 2(1918), 352-383 (see also Dimitrov and Rusev, ZEROS OF ENTIRE FOURIER TRANSFORMS, EAST JOURNAL ON APPROXIMATIONS, Volume 17, Number 1 (2011), 1-108)

***Theorem 3***[Polya (1918)]
If $f(t)$ is positive and increasing for $t\in [0,1]$, then (1)the function $U(f,z):=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\cos(zt)\mathrm{d}t$
has only real and simple zeros.
(2) Each interval $((2k-1)\pi/2, (2k+1)\pi/2), k \in\mathbb{N}$ contains exactly one zero.

We now sketch the proof for Theorem 2.
For $a>0$,we have
$$\mathrm{sinc}(z-ia)+\mathrm{sinc}(z+ia)=2\int_{0}^{1}\cosh(at)\cos(zt)\mathrm{d}t\tag{5}$$

Substitution of this into (1) and separation of the positive terms from the negative terms in (1) and applying (5) leads to the proof of (A).

To apply Polya's theorem to prove (B) and (C), we need to prove that $f_{n,p}(t),p=0,1$ are positive and increasing for $t\in [0,1]$. Thus it is suffice to prove that $f_{n,p}(0)>0$,and $\partial_t f_{n,p}(t)>0,t\in (0,1]$.

Since
$$f_{n,p}(0)=2\sum_{j=1}^{q_n} c_{n,2j-p}>0\tag{6}$$
$$\partial_t f_{n,p}(t)
=\sum_{j=1}^{q_n} c_{n,2j-p}(2j-p+1/4)\ln n\sinh(t(2j-p+1/4)\ln n)>0,\quad t\in (0,1]$$
Thus we prove (B) and (C).

***QUESTION:*** Any thoughts/comments on how to prove ***Proposition 1***?

Because $f_{n,0}(t)-f_{n,1}(t)$ is numerically found to be a decresing function of $t\in[0,1]$, so we can not apply Polya's theorem 2.

One way to prove that $W_{n}(x)=U_{n,0}(x)-U_{n,1}(x)$ is real-rooted is to prove that roots of $U_{n,0}(x)$ and roots of $U_{n,1}(x)$ are interlaced. We are working on it but it seems quite difficult to us.

***UPDATE (1)***
We now add the following result about the roots of $U_{n,p}(x),p=0,1$.
From (1),(2),(3), we obtain:
$$U_{n,p}(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{q_n}c_{n,2j-p}
\left(\mathrm{sinc}(z-i(2j-p+1/4)\ln n)
+\mathrm{sinc}(z+i(2j-p+1/4)\ln n)\right),\quad p=0,1$$
***Lemma 4*** Each interval $((k-1/2)\pi, k\pi), k \in\mathbb{N}$ contains exactly one zero for $U_{n,p}(z)$.
We now sketch the proof. When we study the roots of $U_{n,p}(z)$, since all of them are real, we can set $z$ to be $x$.

Since
$$\mathrm{sinc}(x-ia)+\mathrm{sinc}(x+ia)=\frac{2}{x^2+a^2}\left(a \cos x \sinh a+x \sin x \cosh a\right),$$

We have
$$U_{n,p}(x)=2\cos(x)u_{n,p}(x^2) +2x\sin(x)v_{n,p}(x^2)$$
$$U_{n,p}(x)=2\left((u_{n,p}(x^2))^2+(v_{n,p}(x^2))^2\right)^{-1/2}\cos(x-\arctan(x v_{n,p}(x^2)/u_{n,p}(x^2)))$$

where
$$u_{n,p}(x^2)=\sum_{j=1}^{q_n}c_{n,2j-p}\frac{((2j-p+1/4)\ln n)\sinh ((2j-p+1/4)\ln n)}{x^2+((2j-p+1/4)\ln n)^2}$$

$$v_{n,p}(x^2)=\sum_{j=1}^{q_n}c_{n,2j-p}\frac{\cosh ((2j-p+1/4)\ln n)}{x^2+((2j-p+1/4)\ln n)^2}$$

The zeros for $U_{n,p}(x),p=0,1$ are given by:

$$x-\arctan(x v_{n,p}(x^2)/u_{n,p}(x^2))=2k\pi+\pi/2,\quad k\in \mathbb{N}$$

Or
$$g_{n,p}(|x|):=|x|\tan|x|+\frac{u_{n,p}(x^2)}{v_{n,p}(x^2)}=0$$

Because

$$g_{n,p}((k-1/2)\pi)=-\infty<0,g_{n,p}(k\pi)=\frac{u_{n,p}((k\pi)^2)}{v_{n,p}((k\pi)^2)}>0$$,
so there is one zero for $U_{n,p}(|x|)$ when $|x|\in ((k-1/2)\pi, k\pi)$. No zeros in the rest regions because there $|x| \tan |x|+\frac{u_{n,p}(x^2)}{v_{n,p}(x^2)}>0$. Combining this result with theorem 2(C), we conclude that each interval $((k-1/2)\pi, k\pi), k \in\mathbb{N}$ contains exactly one zero for $U_{n,p}(z)$. Since $U_{n,p}(z)$ is an even function of $z$, each interval $(-k\pi,-(k-1/2)\pi), k \in\mathbb{N}$ also contains exactly one zero for $U_{n,p}(z)$.

***Update (2)***
I posted a related question about how to prove $u_1(x)_1(x)-v_2(x)u_1(x)>0$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658482/how-to-prove-w-2xw-1x).

Comment: What do you mean by real-rooted?

Comment: a function is called real-rooted if all the zeros of it are real.